# Specialize variadic template member function

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Is there a way to get this "fake overloading" argument specialization to work?

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
  template < typename T, typename ... Args > 
  T* bar (Args&& ... args);
};

template <> 
int* Foo::bar()
{
  std::cout << "int* bar()\n";
  return new int;
}

// error: template-id ‘bar<>’ for ‘double* Foo::bar(double)’ does not match any template declaration
template <> 
double* Foo::bar(double d)
{
  std::cout << "double* bar(" << d << ")\n";
  return new double;
}

int main()
{
  Foo f;
  f.bar<int>();
  f.bar<double>(3.0);
}
```

One solution would be to actually overload the function, e.g.

```
class Foo
{
public:
  template < typename T, typename ... Args > 
  T* bar (Args&& ... args);
  template < typename T, typename U > 
  T* bar (U u);
};
```

but I would prefer to avoid that if possible. I am looking at dozens of allowed combinations of return type and arguments, so overloading is impractical.

I assume some SFINAE magic should make it possible to only enable very specific combinations of return type and arguments, but I feel that I'm probably missing a simpler option.

Comment: `template <> double* Foo::bar(double&& d) { ... }` ?

Comment: Ouch... Yes!!! THANK YOU, not sure how I missed that, but I literally spent hours thinking my mistake was in the details of the template specialization. If you put this in an answer I'll approve it immediately. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter type of the specialization `double`, doesn't match the parameter type of the primary template `Args&&`, as the error message said.

The primary template is applying forwarding reference, which could instantiate as both lvalue-reference or rvalue-reference. For rvalue-reference (which matches the usage in `main()`) the specialization should be

```
template <> 
double* Foo::bar(double&& d)
{
  std::cout << "double* bar(" << d << ")\n";
  return new double;
}
```